# Loop all rows in a table PL/SQL then count

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to loop all row in a table and count the appearances of each elements in the table.

I need to find the active player (Active = Y) in the table PLAYER that have much friends. 
I have tried some methods for loop in a table but i did not success.

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER(   
    NO_PLAYER INTEGER           
    Active  CHAR(1) -- Y is yes and N is no
);


CREATE TABLE FRIEND(
    NO_PLAYER_Inviter INTEGER  -- player who invite the others              
    NO_PLAYER_Invited INTEGER  -- player who is invited         
);
```

Suppose in table PLAYER we have players 1 2 3 are actives, player 4 is inactive, then I have these records in table FRIEND

**NOTE**: we accept the duplicate

```
which means
1 2
2 1
2 3
then we say that 2 has 3 friends.
```

```
table FRIEND:
1    2
1    3
1    4  -- we will not consider 4 is a friend of 1 as 4 is inactive
2    1
2    4  -- we will not consider 4 is a friend of 2 as 4 is inactive
3    1
4    3  -- we will not consider 4 is a friend of 3 as 4 is inactive
I expect the result is 
player 1 has 4 friends
player 2 has 2 friends
player 3 has 2 friends
player 4 has 0 friends 

and the code return player 1
```

Comment: Please explain how you arrive at the expected results. You expect player 1 to have 4 friends yet player 1 only occurs 3 as Inviter and 1 of those is not to be counted. Similarly for player 2. Player 3 only occurs 1 time, so how can it have 2 friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `union` as following:

```
select 
    'Player ' || p.no_player
    || ' has ' || count(1) 
    || ' friends' as res
from (select no_player_inviter as no_player from friend
    union all select no_player_invited from friend) f 
join player p on (p.no_player = f.no_player)
Where p.active = 'Y'
group by p.no_player;
```

Also, you can use `inner join` as following:

```
select 'Player ' || p.no_player
        || ' has ' || count(1) 
        || ' friends' as res
from player p
join friends f
on (p.no_player in (f.no_player_inviter, f.no_player_invited))
where p.p.active = 'Y'
group by p.no_player;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If, as suggested by expected result, you don't care about the duplicates, you could use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select 
    player,
    count(*) no_of_friends
from (
    select no_player_inviter player from friend
    union all select no_player_invited from friend
) t
group by player
```